# How to change the OR logic to AND for the "in" keyword in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

When I do a query using the `in` keyword like so:

```
select * from users_roles where user_grp in ('SUPPORTER', 'MEMBER', 'VIP');
```

In this SQL, I'm saying that select those users who are in any *one* of the user group. So this is a OR logic.

But can I change the OR logic to AND so that I'm and selecting records that are in all or the items in the list?

The table structure is simply using a one-to-many relationship, in which one user can be in multiple groups, so there can have multiple rows of the same user in the `users_roles` table with different `user_grp`.

So, how do I write my SQL so that I select users who are in *all* of the user groups?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply group by and then select the data that occurs three times after apllying filter

```
select user_id -- or user_name, whatever
  from users 
 where user_grp in ('SUPPORTER', 'MEMBER', 'VIP')
 group by user_id
having count(distinct user_grp) = 3;
```